# Is there a way to base one column off of two

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new column that uses criteria from two other columns to make an output. Right now I am getting a type mismatch error. Prior to that my output was not coming out at all.

```
Sub FormatcolumnF()

    Dim eqa As Range, eqt As Range, rngResult As Range
    Dim arr_a As Variant, arr_t As Variant
    Dim wks As Worksheet, i As Integer
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    'or even better by name like "Worksheets(Table1)"

    With wks
        'Now that the Worksheet is defined, we'll find the last row number
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'We can now use a Range to grab all the category data
        Set eqa = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1))
        Set eqt = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1))
    End With

    arr_a = eqa
    arr_t = eqt

    Dim result As String

    For i = LBound(arr_a, 1) To UBound(arr_a, 1)
                If arr_a(i, 1) >= arr_t(i, 1) - 0.025 _
                    Or arr_a(i, 1) <= arr_t(i, 1) + 0.025 Then
                    result = "ON TARGET"
                ElseIf arr_a(i, 1) <= arr_t(i, 1) - 0.025 Then
                    result = "UNDER"
                ElseIf arr_a(i, 1) >= arr_t(i, 1) + 0.025 Then
                    result = "OVER"
                End If
    Next i

    With wks
        Set rngResult = .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lngLastRow, 1))
        .Cells(1, 6) = "OVER/UNDER"
    End With

End Sub
```

I need the 6th column on my sheet to reflect a string out put that is based on the loop I created of the 3rd and 4th column. I have a variable amount of rows.

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there were many little things, like a column mismatch on the `Cells` references in side the ranges.

But the major problem is you were not doing anything with the output after assigning it to a variable.  Make that variable an array also then assign that array to the range.

Also test the values to make sure that first they are not Errors(Most likely reason for your type mismatch) or not numeric(second most likely reason).

```
Sub FormatcolumnF()

    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim arr_a As Variant, arr_t As Variant
    Dim wks As Worksheet, i As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    'or even better by name like "Worksheets(Table1)"

    With wks
        'Now that the Worksheet is defined, we'll find the last row number
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        'We can now use a Range to grab all the category data
        'Skip setting ranges and assign directly to the arrays
        arr_a = .Range(.Cells(2, 4), .Cells(lngLastRow, 4)) 'the 1 is column A it should match the 4
        arr_t = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(lngLastRow, 3)) 'the 1 is column A it should match the 3

        'Create an array for the output
        Dim result() As Variant
        ReDim result(1 To UBound(arr_a, 1), 1 To 1) As Variant

        For i = LBound(arr_a, 1) To UBound(arr_a, 1)
            'make sure both arr_a and arr_t are not error and numeric
            If Not IsError(arr_a(i, 1)) And Not IsError(arr_t(i, 1)) Then
                If IsNumeric(arr_a(i, 1)) And IsNumeric(arr_t(i, 1)) Then
                    'Load the output in the array
                    ' Should be And not Or
                    If arr_a(i, 1) >= arr_t(i, 1) - 0.025 _
                        And arr_a(i, 1) <= arr_t(i, 1) + 0.025 Then
                        result(i, 1) = "ON TARGET"
                    ElseIf arr_a(i, 1) <= arr_t(i, 1) - 0.025 Then
                        result(i, 1) = "UNDER"
                    ElseIf arr_a(i, 1) >= arr_t(i, 1) + 0.025 Then
                        result(i, 1) = "OVER"
                    End If
                Else
                    result(i, 1) = "Not Numeric"
                End If
            Else
                result(i, 1) = "Error"
            End If
         Next i

        'load the output array into the cells
        .Range(.Cells(2, 6), .Cells(lngLastRow, 6)) = result
        .Cells(1, 6) = "OVER/UNDER"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So I ran the code and I am receiving the same issue that I experienced before. The only output on the newly created column is "ON TARGET" When that should not be the case @Scott Craner

Comment: Try the edit.  The Or should be an And @tonytwotime

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much @Scott Craner you are an excel genius!

Comment: @tonytwotime please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.